# Rewrite to https and www doesn't work for aliases

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, alias

I read tons of posts about this topic, but still couldn't solve my problem. In my `httpd.conf` I have an alias like `"/folder2" "/home/web/folder1"`. Also I have these lines in my `.htaccess` to rewrite all possible URLs to https://www.:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

This works perfectly except for all URLs with `mydomain.com/folder2`. They still remain in `http://` and in order to acces them with `https://` I have to type it explicitly.

Comment: get sure it is not caching issue

Comment: caching on which side?

Comment: permanent 301 redirects are hard cacheable so you won't know where the response taken from, unless to trace the http-headers.

Answer (score 1):

Good evening :)

Are both, the alias and the rewrites, within the same context (e.g. vhost)? Because if they are not, the alias could be applied before the rewrite and so the rewrite might never 'hit'.

[Read this](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html) for further information on processing order and merging rules.

To fix it, put the rewrite rules first, alias second. Alias should still work and rewrite rules have already been applied by then :)

**EDIT**

The target (or substitution string) in a RewriteRule is assumed to be a file path, by default. The use of the [PT] flag causes it to be treated as a URI instead. That is to say, the use of the [PT] flag causes the result of the RewriteRule to be passed back through URL mapping, so that location-based mappings, such as Alias, Redirect, or ScriptAlias, for example, might have a chance to take effect.

If, for example, you have an Alias for /icons, and have a RewriteRule pointing there, you should use the [PT] flag to ensure that the Alias is evaluated.

Excerpt from [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_pt)

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to the whole httpd.conf. So I should move the rewrite rules from the .htaccess file to httpd.conf?

Comment: Alias is in httpd.conf and rewrites in .htaccess? then yes. or the alias into the htaccess right after the rewrites.

Comment: Aliases are not allowed in htaccess and when I put the rewrites in httpd.conf all domains like subdomains are processed. I tried to put the rewrites inside of <directory "/home/web/folder1">... but there is no effect :(

Comment: So you want these rewrite applied only for THIS subdomain, not all? And you can't put an /Alias in .htaccess...I don't see many options left. Can you implement a vhost? It seems like you have full server access, since you are able to edit httpd.conf?! I'd recomment not using .htaccess all then. It is intended to be used when you don't have access to your server...

Comment: Apache prevents using aliases in htaccess. I want these rules only to be applied to mydomain.com and my alias mydomain.com/folder2. I have access to httpd.conf through the web admin environment, but only to add more stuff, not to edit existing text. So if I made a vhost where would I put the rewrite rules?

Comment: "First, all Redirects are processed before Aliases are processed" --> should matter too much, as long as they are both (alias and rewrites) in the same overall context (like vhost or in your case main apache conf --> httpd.conf)

Comment: Found seomthing that might help: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_pt --> If, for example, you have an Alias for /icons, and have a RewriteRule pointing there, you should use the [PT] flag to ensure that the Alias is evaluated. Maybe you should try that

Comment: Ok, I'm the victim of my own stupidity. The problem was a missing `RewriteEngine on` in the htaccess file. And I don't know why, but it is just working without PT, otherwise it causes a bad request... Anyway, thank you for your effort!

Comment: Also my conclusion is to do https-redirects in the webserver backend of the provider. It really makes everything easier.